# Connect to a GCP Redis instance that is connected to a different VPC network

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-networking

On GCP, peered VPC connections are not transitive and Memorystore exists in it's own VPC network. This means that it's not possible to connect to a Redis instance from multiple VPC networks. Only a single authorized network is able to get access.

This diagram illustrates how VPC-2 cannot connect to VPC-1's Redis instance:

```
[Redis]-[VPC-1]-[VPC-2]
```

The only proposed solution I've found so far to connect from multiple VPC networks is to host a Redis proxy ([nutcracker](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy))
but this feels like a lot of work and potential maintenance in the future.

Is there a managed service offered by GCP that can do the trick?

I've recently connected a private GKE cluster to Cloud Build following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools) which makes use of routers and tunnels, is it possible to use a Cloud Router and VPN tunnels to proxy the connection?

Comment: Another solution with shared vpc was proposed in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/memorystore-redis-access-through-vpc-peering-3bb75e1746d4).

Comment: Use a Shared VPC network: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances#creating_a_redis_instance_on_a_shared_vpc_network_from_a_service_project

Comment: Isnt a Shared VPC for connecting across projects? Or is it safe to make my project a host for a Shared VPC and then connect to it from within the same project?

Comment: Okay I can try that thanks. It seems like a Shared VPC is designed for connecting across projects and not for connecting within the same project. That is possible and safe to do so right?

Comment: For the following reasons it could be [safer](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc)

Comment: Hey, do you confirm if using the shared VPC solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution so you can manage the peered VPCs within the same  project:

As you know, peered VPCs are not transitive, in this case meaning your VPC-2 does not know about the connection between VPC-1 and Redis VPC.

You can use VPC-1 as a transit network, by either importing and exporting routes between VPC-1 and VPC-2 or for a more managed solution you could use Cloud VPN on your VPC-1. If you have multiple VPCs that you need to connect to Redis, I would suggest considering using the Cloud VPN.

Here is an [example of how this architecture could work](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#transit-network)
From this example, look at **network-b** as your **VPC-1** and **Network-a** as your **Redis VPC** and **Network-c** as your **VPC-2**.

If you only have a few VPCs that need to connect to the Redis VPC, you could also consider [exporting and importing  custom routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#importing-exporting-routes) from VPC-1 to all peered VPC that need access to Redis.

For Redis please note that [only IPs from RFC1918 are allowed to connect](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/networking#supported_and_unsupported_networks) so your IPs that need to connect to Redis would need to be in these ranges

```
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```